# Do iOS configuration profiles have a maximum size?

Tags: ios, configuration-profile

I'm trying to install a configuration profile with iOS with a large font payload (a Chinese language font) but it simply opens the configuration profile list on my iPhone which says "No configuration profiles installed". Is there a maximum size for configuration profiles? The font is 25MB, so I'm wondering if that's what's making it do that.

Answer (score 1):

From the Xcode logs it says 
mc_mobile_tunnel[307] : (Error) MC: Message size 34024201 exceeds limit of 20971520 bytes
So the profile size is limited to 20 MB.